# PDF base64 shows empty in Google chrome and Egde

Tags: c#, object, pdf, embed, frame

I want to load pdf from Db and display in my site (Blazor). I tried to use `embed/object/frame` and it is working in `Firefox`, but **not** working in `Google Chrome` and `Edge`. Here is my file in JsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/fhd30bko/

When I open this url in Firefox, it shows my file correctly, but it shows empty when I open in Google Chrome or Edge. Any ideas for this error?

Comment: Bug of Chrome?: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/28413759/certain-pdfs-display-blank-when-displayed-using-base64-string?hl=en